# Web Automation to go to the next page - Invoking method that returns Promise within await block) - await is only valid in async

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, web-scraping, automation, puppeteer

**Background:**

I am writing a Nodejs script with puppeteer to web scrape data from a web page. I'm not familiar with Nodejs, promises, or puppeteer. I've tried many things and done research for a few days.

**Application Flow:**

1. With automation, go to a website
2. Scrape data from the page, push to an array
3. If there is a "next page" click the next page button
4. Scrape data from the page, push to same array
5. Repeat

**Problem:**

My problem is with #3. With web automation, clicking the next page button. 
All I want, is to use the .click() method in puppeteer, to click on the button selector. However, .click() returns a Promise. Since it's a promise, I need keyword `await`, but you can't have `await` in the for loop (or any block other than `async`).

**What Have I Tried:**

I've tried creating another `async` function, with statements for `await page.click();`and calling that function in the problem area. I've tried creating a regular function with page.click() and calling that in the problem area. Refactoring everything to have it not work as well. I'm not really understanding Promises and Async/Await even after reading about it for a few days.

**What I Want Help With:**

Help with invoking the .click() method inside the problem area or any help with selecting the 'Next Page' using web automation.

**Pseudo Code:**

```
let scrape = async () => {
    await //do.some.automation;

    const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
        for (looping each page) {
            if (there is a next page) {
                for (loop through data) {
                    array.push(data);
                    //----PROBLEM----
                    //use automation to click the selector of the next page button
                    //--------------   
                }
            }
        }
        return data;
    });
    //close browser
    return result;
};
scrape().then((value) => {
    //output data here;
    });
});
```

**All Code:**

```
let scrape = async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false 
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto("GO TO A WEBSITE");
    await page.click("CLICK A BUTTON");
    await page.waitFor(2000);

    //Scraping
    const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
        let pages = document.getElementsByClassName("results-paging")[2];
        let allPages = pages.getElementsByClassName("pagerLink");
        let allJobs = [];
        //Loop through each page
        for (var j = 0; j < allPages.length; j++) {
            let eachPage = pages.getElementsByClassName("pagerLink")[j].innerHTML;
            if (eachPage) {
                //Scrape jobs on single page
                let listSection = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[2];
                let allList = listSection.getElementsByTagName("li");
                for (var i = 0; i < allList.length; i++) {
                    let eachList = listSection.getElementsByTagName("li")[i].innerText;
                    allJobs.push(eachList);

                    //--------PROBLEM-------------
                    await page.click('#selector_of_next_page');
                    //----------------------------  
                }
            }
            else {
                window.alert("Fail");
            }
        }
        return allJobs;
    });
    browser.close();
    return result;
};

scrape().then((value) => {
    let data = value.join("\r\n");
    console.log(data);
    fs.writeFile("RESULTS.txt", data, function (err) {
        console.log("SUCCESS MESSAGE");
    });
});
```

**Error Message:**

> SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Comment: Try adding `async` to the `page.evaluate` arrow function.

Comment: You can not use `page.click` method inside `page.evaluate` function.

Comment: @GabrielBleu I'm sorry can you elaborate? do you mean ``const result = async page.evaluate(()=> {}`` ?

Comment: I'm sure he means this: `await page.evaluate(async () => {})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use `page` methods inside `page.evaluate` function.

Based on your example you should change

```
await page.click('#selector_of_next_page');
```

to native JS equivalent

```
document.getElementById('selector_of_next_page').click();
```

Comment: I've added that but there is no click event happening.

Comment: @AnthonyDellavecchia It's difficult to help you in this scenario since you didn't provide a real site to perform tests.

Comment: The site is from State Farm's job posting website, it's for scraping job posting information. If I do ``document.getElementById('selector_of_next_page").innerHTML`` I can see that it's getting the correct element. But it's not being clicked when I used .click()

Comment: @AnthonyDellavecchia so edit your question with this data to be more reproducible